# Frechet derivative of the sup norm function on $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I know that the derivative in the title does not exist for any x but I do not have a clue why.  Could someone explain why this derivative DNE at 0 and I can figure out why it does not exist at x? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$0$ is too easy: no directional derivative of the sup norm function exists there.
It's harder to show that the Frechet derivative doesn't exist at, for example, the function $f(t) = t$.